# Python sort text file into a new format into another text file

Tags: python

Using python I need to take the contents of a text file e.g

http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=DsBg6ud8 (the text file)

Python code to open file

```
file = open('file.txt', 'r')
```

Now I need to take each section which is separated by "------------------" and rearrange it into its own line in the format of `"internal://user:class@id"`. Internal is a constant that just exists in the new file not from the old and the user, class and id are taken from the old file.

Unfortunately I don't know how to do this, could you please help?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service!

Comment: If you show your own attempts at the problem, and outline what research you have done, you'll find people are willing to help. What people are not willing to do however is just hand you a solution when it is not clear if you have even made an attempt.

Comment: Honestly the fact that you've both not even attempted to help and point me in the right direction should be clear enough that you shouldn't post. You can clearly see that I do not know where to go or what to search for in regards to help so please be courteous..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not giving you the code, only one of the ways of doing it.

1. Iterate through the file.
2. If `line == "------------------"`, it implies a new set of data is going to start.
   Hence create a blank data structure in which you will store the upcoming data. (eg- `dict`)
3. Else: Split the line on `":"` character. And store the first part as key, and second part as value of the dict.
4. Finally using the dict, print your desired output in a new file.

If you have any doubts regarding how to implement these individual steps, then google/SO it. I'm sure you'll find the answers.